# How to use MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE flag in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysql-connect, database-connection

So we can add a flag to Wordpress database. I can see it in `wp-db.php`. I see this code:

```
$client_flags = defined( 'MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS' ) ? MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS : 0;
```

But I couldn't see anywhere I can define `MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS`. Where should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this in `wp-config.php`

```
/** The MySQL connection type which is interactive. It will use interactive_timeout instead of wait_timeout.*/
define('MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS', MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE);
```